# I cannot retrieve the field to integrate it into my table because of the quotes do you have a solution to the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, api, rest

I cannot retrieve the field to integrate it into my table because of the quotes do you have a solution to the problem?

```
10003: {Date: "2020-10-18 07:30:00", Email: "geraldine.daniel1@free.fr", BounceCode: "smtp;550 spam detected", "BounceType ": "Blocked"}
```

Note that BounceType is the only field that has: "

Here is the code where I want to inject my data

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table100-head">
                               <th class="column3">BounceType</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                       <tbody>
                        <tr>
           
                           <td class="column3">${user.BounceType}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: use ${user["BounceType "]} to get the value

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can you please share your complete json data?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code snippet. You can access the object key value using [] in javascript.

```js
 var data = {Date: "2020-10-18 07:30:00", Email: "geraldine.daniel1@free.fr", BounceCode: "smtp;550 spam detected", "BounceType ": "Blocked"}

    document.getElementById("column1").innerHTML = data["BounceType "];
    document.getElementById("column2").innerHTML = data.Email;
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr class="">
         <th class="column3">BounceType</th>
         <th class="column3">Email</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td id="column1"></td>
         <td id="column2"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
// Fonction de convertion

    function csvJSON(csv) {
    const lines = csv.split('\n');
    const result = [];
    const headers = lines[0].split(',');
 
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (!lines[i]) continue;
      const obj = {};
      const currentline = lines[i].split(',');
 
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }
      result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
  }

function boutonSubmit(){
bounceType = document.getElementById('BouncesType').value;
datestart = document.getElementById('dateS').value;
dateend = document.getElementById('dateE').value;
//bounceCode = getElementById('#dateS').value;   
// Récupération des donnèes et convertion     
        fetch(`https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((txtResponse) => {
            const data = csvJSON(txtResponse);
// Ciblage sur la page HTML
            const tbody = document.querySelector('#user-table tbody');
// INSERTION DES DONNEES DE LAPI DANS LE CORPS DU TABLEAU

// Pour tous nouveaux utilisateurs on crée un nouveau élement <tr>
        data.forEach( (user) => {
            const entry = document.createElement('tr')
       
// On insère les donnèes de l'API
        entry.innerHTML = `
            <tr>
                <td class="column1">${user.Date}</td>
                <td class="column2">${user.Email}</td>
                <td class="column3">${user.BounceCode}</td>
                <td class="column4">${user["BounceType "]}</td>
            </tr>   
            `;
  
            tbody.appendChild(entry);
                });
            })
}
```